# addEventListener in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, addeventlistener

I'm new in this nice community. I am a young student in computer science and I'm trying to develope a web based app to help both sighted people and people with visual empairment to learn typing. My project was blocked by the following problem:
Given a string, I need to verify that the user has pressed the key that corresponds to the first character. If it is correct, the program should test the next character, until the end of the string.
The most natural solutions seems to be a loop, like that:

```
        do {
        var checkCharacter=lessons[exerciceNumber][2].substr(charNumber, 1);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', testKey);
    }
    while (charNumber<=lessons[exerciceNumber][2].length-1);
```

When I run the script, nothing appears and it seems it doesn't detect the pressed keys. Can you help me please?
Inorder to understand the context, I'll attach the entire file.

```
<?php
include "config.php";
//Select fields from database
$sql="SELECT lesson_number, exercice_number, text FROM lessons";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
//Pass variables to javascript
$output="<script> var lessons=new Array(); ";
while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output.="lessons.push([
        ".$row["lesson_number"].",
        ".$row["exercice_number"].",
        '".$row["text"]."']);";
}
$output.="</script>";
echo $output;
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Impara a scrivere</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="lesson"></h2>
    <p id="instructions"></p>
    <p id="check"></p>
    <p id="keyList"></p>
</body>
<script>
    //define variables
    var keys="";
    var exerciceNumber=0;
    var charNumber=0;
    //Function to play the sounds
    function sound(name) {
        var audio=new Audio(name+'.mp3');
        audio.play();}
    document.getElementById("lesson").innerHTML="Lezione "+lessons[exerciceNumber][0];
    document.getElementById("instructions").innerHTML="Esercizio "+lezioni[exerciceNumber][1]+": scrivi <b>"+lessons[exrciceNumber][2]+"</b>.";
    //function to check pressed keys
    funtion testKey(event) {
        if (event.key==checkCharacter) {
            sound ("right");
            keys+=event.key;
            document.getElementById("keyList").innerHTML=keys;
        } else {
            sound("wrong");
        }
    }
    //loop for the exercices
    do {
        var checkCharacter=lessons[exerciceNumber][2].substr(charNumber, 1);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', testKey);
    }
    while (charNumber<=lessons[exerciceNumber][2].length-1);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: For one, you seem to be repeatedly adding the event listener. I'm pretty sure you'd only need add it once. It doesn't get removed after it's used.

Comment: An event listener doesn't go away after the event happened once. It keeps listening until it's specifically removed, with [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add an event listener multiple times, that will cause it to fire once. To avoid this, try using `onkeydown`. For example, something like this should work:

```js
    do {
        const checkCharacter = lessons[exerciceNumber][2].substr(charNumber, 1);
        document.onkeydown = (evt) => {
            testKey();
        };
    } while (charNumber <= lessons[exerciceNumber][2].length - 1);
```

Also, I'm not entirely sure of what you're trying to do here, but instead of using a loop you can do something like this:

```js
form.onsubmit = (evt) => {
     const input = someInput.value;
     if (testKey() === input) {
        return true; // Or whatever you want
     }
};
```

Hoped this helped!

Comment: But why are you still adding `document.onkeydown` multiple times? If the string is 50 characters long, you will overwrite `document.onkeydown` 50 times? What's the point?

Comment: This isn't my code, you can ask the owner of this post why.

Comment: Well this is your answer, and it's supposed to improve the code, isn't it? :) You could go the extra mile and suggest to not add 100 `onkeydown`. That's why I said "Why are you _still_ adding", like in the original code (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @JeremyThille I added what you asked for. I don't know exactly what the post owner is doing, So I just put as the owner said. If you know what he/she wants, I can update my post correctly.